# how to get that Business intelligence Option in VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, business-intelligence

i would like to start a report(SSRS) project in VS 2008.

I could not find Business inteligence project> report project in my VS 2008.

How can i get it..?

am using VS 2008 professional edition.!!

Answer (score 1):

Hi as Rikalous has said you need to install Business Intelligence Development Studio. This can be found under the Client tools in your SQL Server 2008 installation wizard. You can optionally go to Programs and Features and click on Add/Change when you have selected SQL Server 2008 and then click on the Add option.

You should then be asked for the SQL 2008 installation media and you will have the option to install BIDS (Business Intelligence Development Studio) under the Client Tools section in your installation.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is Business Intelligence Developer Studio - this is a cut-down version of VS2008.

You get this by installing the reporting services client tools, which will either install a version of VS2008 (if it's not already installed), or, in your case, it will add the appropriate project types to your existing VS2008 install.

Comment: Reporting services client means..??

Comment: Use the SQL Server installation disk - it's got all the stuff on it. I don't think there is a stand-alone SSRS installer.

Comment: I need this as well (the cut-down version of VS 2008) .. is this only available in the SQL Server 2008 r2 installer.. or will the more recent versions of the SQL installers still get me the SSRS report authoring option via Client Tools?